# Examples to attain the largest possible value of the Hausdorff dimension of intersection

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I am studying fractals and have come to a section about the intersection of fractals. Falconer, in his Fractal Geometry book, proves (partially) a result about the intersect of a set and a translation of a set:

**Theorem 8.1.** Let $E,F$ be Borel susbets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $$\dim_{H}(E\cap(F+x))\leqslant\max\{0,\dim_{H}(E\times F)-n\}$$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$E\times F$ is the Cartesian product of $E$ and $F$, and $\dim_{H}$ denotes the Hausdorff dimension.

I am fine with the partial proof of it, but he goes on to say "suitable examples show that this is the best we can hope for". But he doesn't give any examples.

Does anyone know of any I can look at?

Comment: Well, there is a trivial case $E=F=\mathbb{R}^n$...

Comment: For those of us without the book, can you say what $dim_H$ denotes, and whether the "cross" in $E \times F$ denotes the cartesian product of the two sets in $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$, please?

Comment: You can add to that trivial case the one where $E$ is all points with $x_1 < 0$ and $F$ is all points with $x_1 > 0$, and $x = 0$; in that case, the dimension of the intersection is...well, I don't know what dimension the author assigns to the empty set...but presumably it's zero.

Comment: @JohnHughes. $\dim_{H}$ denotes the Hausdorff dimension and yes, the $\times$ is Cartesian product. These are both good examples, thank you both. Do you know of any non-trivial examples?